# Screen navigation by using dynamic links in react native

Tags: firebase, react-native, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

I created dynamic link and it's working fine for both android and ios, now I want to navigate it to different screen by using dynamic links if app is installed.How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any framework there is some entry point  in react native there is app.js. When app is installed then it will going to run entry point file. In that file we can write a code for navigation to different screens. Use react native navigation and routes it will help alot to do so. And check for link if matches the navigate to particular component.